# Is this a reasonable implementation of the quadratic Bézier function in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml, bezier

A friend came across a quadratic Bézier curve function in his codebase that used a gigantic rats nest of a switch table to perform the computation.  He challenged me to find a single, short expression that would allow him to replace the gigantic block of code.

In attempting to satisfy two different curiosities, I thought I'd try implementing the function in OCaml.  I'm a very novice OCaml programmer and I'm also unfamiliar with the function and this *specific* implementation is hard to come by via Google.

Critiques on both the function's performance/correctness as well as its implementation are very much appreciated.

Implementation of [Quadratic Bézier Curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Quadratic_B.C3.A9zier_curves):

```
let rec b2 n =
  let p1 = -10. in
  let p2 = 10. in
  let q = n*.n in
  let rec b2i n i hd =
    if i > n then
      List.rev hd
    else
      let t = i /. n in
      b2i n (i+.1.) ((((1.-.t)**2.)*.p1+.(2.*.t*.(1.-.t)*.q)+.(t**2.)*.p2) :: hd)
  in 
  b2i n 0. []
;;

let floatprint lst = 
  List.iter (fun f -> Printf.printf "%f; " f) lst ;;

floatprint (b2 8.);;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

b2 isn't recursive, so no need for [let rec b2 n =].  Since n never changes, no need to have it as argument to b2i, just use n from the enclosing scope.  Your inner function should depend on p0, p1 and p2, but I see it depending on -10., n**2 and 10.  The function also has the form of a map from [ 0.0; 1.0; 2.0; ...; n.0] to the final values.  Could you write it:

```
let b i = 
  let t = i /. n in
  let tminus = (1.-.t) in
  (tminus *. tminus *. p0) +. (2. *. t *. tminus *. p1) +. (t *. t * p2)
in
List.map b ([generate list 1.0; 2.0; ... n.0])
```

A function to generate the list 1.0...n.0 could be:  (for small n)

```
let rec count m n = if m > n then [] else m :: (count (m+.1.) n)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have two suggestions:

You should call `List.rev` after `b2i` returns so ocaml can exploit it's tail-recursion optimizations. I am not sure how well OCaml will deal with the current implementation, `List.rev` is tail-recursive though. You'll notice that in [this post](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/old_caml_site/caml-list/2115.html) it is done like that.

Also, you can make the resolution of the iteration be an optional argument like `?(epsilon=0.1)`.

As an ocaml programmer I don't see much wrong here aside from that --as long as P1 and P2 are in fact constants. Compile it down and see what the difference in assembly is between moving List.rev inside or out of the tail-recursion.

Comment: the list.rev codepath will not affect b2i's tail recursion.  Good idea on epsilon.  Probably p1 and p2 should become arguments too.